# How is the phrase 'note of discord' used?

Tags: word-usage

In the Cambridge dictionary, the word 'discord' means the state of not agreeing or sharing opinions. Yet, I saw the word used in 'note of discord' in sentences in example sentences such as 'A note of discord has crept into relations between the two countries', and I would like to know whether this is a phrase to express disagreement between two parties, or an other meaning?What does the word 'note' mean here? Could more examples using this phrase be given?

Comment: Did you do any researh yourself? Did you search the Web, Google Books, etc. for that phrase? If so, then what did you find, and why were those examples not sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a "note of discord" is a commonly-used play on words (pun). "Discord" meaning, "notes that are not harmonically related, i.e., sound 'bad' played together," and "discord," disagreement. So, as you state, it 'sounds' as if the parties are not in agreement.